# Code to connect NSbutton to a method to load a NSView from Xib

Tags: swift, macos, nsview

I'm working on my first app. I have some NSButtons that I would like to connect so that each button would load a different subview into an existing NSView. I'm still pretty new to this and I'm struggling with the best way to code this.

I have a class to handle the button actions, this just shows one for brevity:

```
class SelectorTest: NSObject {

@objc class func printButton1Pushed(_ sender: NSButton) {
print("button one pushed")

ContentView.showView1()

}
}
```

The above works fine, the string is printed to the console when the button is pushed. It gives a "Result of call to 'showView1()' is unused" error though. I guess I'm struggling with what to put in the showview1() method in the ContentView class.

I have a view created, a .xib and a class called the same thing. This works fine if I add as a subview and run the app. How to I load it when the button is pressed? This is the code I have so far, the button does not load the view:

```
class ContentView: NSView {

static let cView = NSView()


class func showView1() -> NSView {

    let view1 = TestView()
    cView.addSubview(view1.view)
    return cView
}
}
```

Edit: More infö about the project. I have a main view controller. Added to that as a subview I have a NSStackview comprising a view for the buttons on the left and a view on the right where each view called by the NSButtons will hopefully be displayed.

After a little more reading, I think that the "Result of call to 'showView1()' is unused" error means, "hey, you called this method, it returned an NSView for you, but you didn't use it for anything". I'm stuck on this part, how do I update the view to show the view I just created?

Comment: FIrst question: Where do the buttons live? Presumably you have an initial view?  Also, are there view controllers? Might help to show more of your code to put all this in context. (And is there a reason you're not using storyboard/nib?)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ron. I'll update the question with more info.

Comment: What is `SNView`?

Comment: El - a typo, fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. (Made it a second answer, rather than editing my previous one, because the previous one is already long enough. I'm still new here, and I hope this isn't against any rules. Not trying to game the reputation thing :)

The main view controller is still generated from the storyboard.

If this is somewhat verbose, I just wanted to show all the machinery. There are doubtless many other ways to do the same thing.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
// Initializing these objects here eliminates optionals
    let stackView = NSStackView(views: [makeView(.purple), makeView(.black)])
    let redButton = labeledButton("Red", action: #selector(showRed))
    let greenButton = labeledButton("Green", action: #selector(showGreen))
    let blueButton = labeledButton("Blue", action: #selector(showBlue))
// Action handlers are objective-c functions. @IBAction implies that
    @objc func showRed(_ sender: Any) {
        stackView.arrangedSubviews[1].layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
    }
    @objc func showGreen(_ sender: Any) {
        stackView.arrangedSubviews[1].layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.green.cgColor
    }
    @objc func showBlue(_ sender: Any) {
        stackView.arrangedSubviews[1].layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor
    }
// Helper to make multiple buttons. Static so it can initialize instance properties
    class func labeledButton(_ stringValue: String = "", action: Selector) -> NSButton {
        let button = NSButton()
        button.action = action
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.bezelStyle = NSButton.BezelStyle.rounded
        button.title = stringValue
        return button
    }
// Helper to make multiple views. Also must be static
    class func makeView(_ color: NSColor) -> NSView {
        let vw = NSView()
        vw.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        vw.wantsLayer = true
        vw.layer?.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
        return vw
    }

    private func createStackView() {
// Configure & add the stack view
        stackView.orientation = .horizontal
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(stackView)
// Pin it to the enclosing view
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
// Set widths of subviews, and pin them to the stack view
        stackView.arrangedSubviews[0].widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        stackView.arrangedSubviews[1].widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 300).isActive = true
        stackView.arrangedSubviews[0].topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.arrangedSubviews[1].topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.arrangedSubviews[0].bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.arrangedSubviews[1].bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
 // Add the buttons to the left view
        stackView.arrangedSubviews[0].addSubview(redButton)
        stackView.arrangedSubviews[0].addSubview(greenButton)
        stackView.arrangedSubviews[0].addSubview(blueButton)
// Space them vertically, and center them horizontally
        redButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.arrangedSubviews[0].centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        greenButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.arrangedSubviews[0].centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        blueButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.arrangedSubviews[0].centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        redButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.arrangedSubviews[0].topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
        greenButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.arrangedSubviews[0].centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        blueButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.arrangedSubviews[0].bottomAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createStackView()
    }


}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply, thanks for this! I'll work through it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of what I think (and I'm probably wrong) you want to do, done with storyboard. If you prefer doing things programmatically, that's only a few more lines of code, but the easiest way to build that IMO is with auto layout, which would clutter up the demo code.

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    var stackedViews = [NSView]()

    @IBAction func showRed(_ sender: Any) {
        stackedViews[1].layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
    }
    @IBAction func showGreen(_ sender: Any) {
        stackedViews[1].layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.green.cgColor
    }
    @IBAction func showBlue(_ sender: Any) {
        stackedViews[1].layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        guard let sView = view.subviews[0] as? NSStackView else {
            print("No StackView")
            return
        }
        for v in sView.arrangedSubviews {
            stackedViews.append(v)
        }
        stackedViews[0].wantsLayer = true
        stackedViews[0].layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.black.cgColor
        stackedViews[1].wantsLayer = true
        stackedViews[1].layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.purple.cgColor
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


}
```

Hope this is helpful.

The storyboard outline looks like this:
[image]

And the storyboard looks like this:

[image]

Result looks like this:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, I really appreciate the help! Would it be possible to include the extra code to do this programmatically? As I mentioned, I'm still just learning the basics and I want to do as much in code as possible.

Comment: I actually prefer that approach myself. I'll do that, but I've got a few things to do first.

Comment: No problem Ron, I appreciate the help!